# Find out who is logged in on linux using python

Tags: python, linux

I have 8 servers that I would like to monitor. All servers have a tornado python server installed. One of the servers is a monitor that polls other servers and alerts me by SMS if there is a problem.

One of the alerts is when a user logs into one of the servers.

How can I use Python to detect who is logged in on my Ubuntu server?
I need to return logged in users to the main monitor.
I hope this makes things clear..

Comment: Good for you. What have you tried?

Comment: @Inbar You shouldn't put answers into the question.

Comment: @it was the OP's answer.... if you didnt notice...

Comment: @InbarRose: Still doesn't make sense to put it in the question. See [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: @slhck it doesnt make sense for the OP to put that as an answer instead of a question either.

Comment: @InbarRose: Have you read the blog entry I linked?

Comment: @DavidRobinson i am aware of that, but looking at the context, and the fact that the OP is a new user, 1+1=2 and it seems that answer is part of the question.

Comment: @InbarRose: I don't even know what that means. The question isn't very good (it needs a lot more detail), but that doesn't mean the encouragement to post what solutions he's found as an answer doesn't apply to him (he's not that new a user, anyway- he's asked and answered a couple of questions).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best thing I found online is `psutil`.
See the [psutil documentation](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

First install psutil :

```
pip install psutil
```

After that everything is easy as an example run python console from terminal:

```
import psutil 

psutil.users()
```

**Output:**

```
[user(name='root', terminal='pts/0', host='your-local-host-from-isp.net',
started=1358152704.0)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, and run the command `who`.

```
In [5]: import subprocess

In [6]: subprocess.check_output("who")
Out[6]: 'monty    pts/0        2013-01-14 16:21 (:0.0)\n'
```

You can fetch the number of current logins using : `who | wc -l`:

```
In [42]: !who
monty    pts/2        2013-01-14 19:09 (:0.0)
monty    pts/0        2013-01-14 19:07 (:0.0)

In [43]: p=Popen(["who"],stdout=PIPE)

In [44]: Popen(["wc","-l"],stdin=p.stdout).communicate()[0]
2
```

Names of the users:

```
In [54]: users=check_output("who")

In [55]: set([x.split()[0] for x in users.splitlines()])
Out[55]: set(['monty'])
```

Comment: Don't you think subprocess is a very bad practice? + You have to parse things in order to get the user name or number of users.

Comment: @Avia see the edited solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

who = Popen(['who'],stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
print who.stdout.read()

# Output 
>>> sudo_O  :0           2013-01-14 11:48 (:0)
>>> sudo_O  pts/0        2013-01-14 11:48 (:0)
>>> sudo_O  pts/1        2013-01-14 12:41 (:0)
>>> sudo_O  pts/2        2013-01-14 12:42 (:0)
```

Comment: This seems like a bad solution since: a) I have to use an external process. b) If I want to read the data into my program I have to parse it and wny changes in the who command output will make my software not work

Comment: @Avia the only way you can consider this a bad solution is if you make those points in your question before hand.

Comment: @Avia your question was just: **I am trying to use python to detect who is logged in on my Ubuntu server.**, you didn't define good and bad.

Answer (score 0):

And if you dont want to install 3-rd party software. You can always run unix **who** utility

```
import os
os.popen('who').read()
```

Comment: i think using `os.popen` is frowned upon now, that's what the `subprocess` module is supposed to replace.

Comment: that's right, but where it's doesn't really matters

Answer (score -1):

```
In [1]: import subprocess
In [2]: print subprocess.check_output("who").split()[0]
Out[3]: 'rikatee'
```

Comment: This will only print the first user in the list.