# How to get current login time in Ubuntu/Linux using python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, authentication

From current login time, I mean the time at which the user logged into the system.

Edit : I only need to get the current login time in hh:mm format, not the username and all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out who is logged in on linux using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319023/find-out-who-is-logged-in-on-linux-using-python)

Comment: @Andy Please see the edit in the question

Comment: That dupe target still gets you all the information you need. You have to add one step to convert the timestamp to a datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
print subprocess.check_output("who").split()[3]
```

Output:

```
22:23
```

Which is in `hh:mm` format.